# sed command to change date format

Tags: date, unix, sed, format, command

Here is a snippet of the file I'm working with:

```
709ENVUN07,SET1,FE10,GB0009252882,GB,GBX,NULL,S,O,LO,1510.00000000,173,N,F,28022007,07:51:15,3717
208ATNHG07,SET1,FE10,GB0009252882,GB,GBX,NULL,S,O,LO,1550.00000000,1800,N,F,18012007,15:48:21,654681
```

As you can see the date is in this format: `28022007`, `18012007`

Using sed I've successfully changed to the format I wish.

```
    gzip -dc allGlaxoOrderHistory.CSV.gz |sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(2[0-9]\{3\}\)/\1-\2-\3/g' > newOrderHistory.csv
```

However sed is also changing `GB0009252882` to `GB00-09-252882` as you can see below

```
709ENVUN07,SET1,FE10,GB00-09-252882,GB,GBX,NULL,S,O,LO,1510.00000000,173,N,F,28-02-2007,07:51:15,3717
208ATNHG07,SET1,FE10,GB00-09-252882,GB,GBX,NULL,S,O,LO,1550.00000000,1800,N,F,18-01-2007,15:48:21,654681
```

Question is how do I change `28022007`, `18012007` to this `28-02-2007` ,`18-01-2007` without `GB0009252882` changing too.

Answer (score 1):

[edit]

Your date field is the 15th from the start. You can write your pattern like this:

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{14\}..\)\(..\)/\1-\3-/'
```

Where `,[^,]*,` describes a field (with separator).

You can also work by fields more easily with awk. You only need to set the input and output delimiter to `,`

With awk (Gnu), target the 15th field:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$15=gensub(/(..)(..)(....)/, "\\1-\\2-\\3", "g", $15)}1' yourfile
```

The parameter `-F,` set the input delimiter and `-vOFS=,` the output delimiter. The `1` at the end is used as a shortcut for `print`).

Comment: With the end of line anchor you _definitely_ don't need the `/g` global modifier.

Comment: Date isn't my last field as you can view below: 709ENVUN07,SET1,FE10,GB0009252882,GB,GBX,NULL,S,O,LO,1510.00000000,173,N,F,28022007,07:51:15,3717

Comment: Never used the awk before please enlighten my on how to use it for this example

Comment: @Hassan ... if there are no other 8-digit fields you can (symbolically) `s/,DDMMYYYY,/,DD-MM-YYYY,/` ... that is, include the surrounding commas in the match, and be sure to put them back in the replacement. You should also edit your question with this full record -- with only the partial 3-field example your question was misleading.

Comment: @StephenP thanks, Ive changed the question to demonstrate the full field as requested, however s/,DDMMYYYY,/,DD-MM-YYYY,/ is not doing any thing

Comment: @Hassan - I said _symbolically_; I didn't mean _literally_ `,DDMMYYYY,` ... I wasn't going to try to fit the whole regex in my comment.  You still need all your grouped `([0-9]{2})` etc. with proper escaping. But I also agree with Casimir — with many fixed fields, _awk_ is a better choice than _sed._